# php mysql table with horizontal headings

Tags: php, mysql

horizontal headings keep displaying for every row. I want the headings to just display for only the top row. What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM timeSheet, timeSheetUsers WHERE timeSheet.userName=timeSheetUsers.userName AND timeSheet.userName=? ORDER BY startTime ASC");

if ($sql->execute(array($_SESSION['userName']))) {
  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo "<table border ='1'>";
         echo 
         "<tr>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>date</th>           
            <th>starTime</th>
            <th>endTime</th>
            <th>total</th>                               
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>" . $row['userName'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['startTime'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['endTime'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>      
         </tr>";
    echo "</table>";
  }
}
```

### ## Resulting Page ##

[image]

Comment: Take `echo "<table border ='1'>";
         echo 
         "<tr>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>date</th>           
            <th>starTime</th>
            <th>endTime</th>
            <th>total</th>                               
         </tr>` and `echo "</table>";` out of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have given row containing headers for table(th) in loop, change it and make them outsite the while loop

like

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM timeSheet, timeSheetUsers WHERE timeSheet.userName=timeSheetUsers.userName AND timeSheet.userName=? ORDER BY startTime ASC");

if ($sql->execute(array($_SESSION['userName']))) {
echo "<table border ='1'>";
         echo "<tr>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>date</th>           
            <th>starTime</th>
            <th>endTime</th>
            <th>total</th>                               
         </tr>";
  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo
        " <tr>
            <td>" . $row['userName'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['startTime'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['endTime'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>      
         </tr>";

  }
 echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The heading should not be part of the while loop, this should work

```
if ($sql->execute(array($_SESSION['userName']))) {
    echo "<table border ='1'>";
     echo 
     "<tr>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>date</th>           
        <th>starTime</th>
        <th>endTime</th>
        <th>total</th>                               
     </tr>";
     while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo  "<tr>
                 <td>" . $row['userName'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['startTime'] . "</td>
                 <td>" . $row['endTime'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>      
              </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
}
```